# ODBC Connection String with MultiSubNetFailover

Tags: r, sql-server, rodbc

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server through R's `RODBC` package. I can consistently use the connection string against a sandbox server we have but when I try to connect to another server the connection is sporadic at best.

I've tried Googling and searching stack overflow for other instances where people can connect successfully to a SQL Server but have issues with MultiSubnetFailover. From what I can tell, `RODBC` does not have an additional argument to turn it on or off.

```
odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=%SERVER%;database=%DATABASE%;trusted_connection=true')

odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=%SERVER%;database=%DATABASE%;trusted_connection=true; MultiSubnetFailover=true')

odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=%SERVER%;database=%DATABASE%;trusted_connection=true; MultiSubnetFailover=yes')

Error received:
Error in sqlQuery(dbhandle, "\nSELECT \n                ") : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel
```

Again, sometimes this works against production. This always works against our sandbox environment. Is there a way to make this consistently connect in R or is there another method?

Comment: Do you capture the return value from `odbcDriverConnect`, as in `dbhandle <- odbcDriverConnect('...')`?

Comment: @r2evans good question. Sorry for not making that clear. I do. I store it as dbhandle <- dbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=%SERVER%;database=%DATABASE%;trusted_connection=true') and then pass the dbhandle to sqlQuery(dbhandle, QUERY). This works against a sandbox environment and has worked against production, but it only works intermittently when used against the production server.

Comment: Ok ... I asked the same question of a recent question (since deleted) where the answer was "oops", meaning the fact that it worked for some time meant that it had been created previously and just not *re*-created (correctly). If this is the case, do you get any errors or messages on the connection attempt? It seems like the error message is on subsequent (not-included) code. (I use `odbc` and not `RODBC`, so it's possible/likely that I'm missing something obvious, my apologies if so.)

Comment: @r2evans Just so I understand. I think you are proposing that it is an open/closed connection issue and/or I need to close the connection or reuse an existing connection? What I've noticed is that in the odbcDriverConnect connect statement is that when I use SANDBOX as the server, it works fine. When I use PRODUCTION it gives me the error as stated in my original post. However, the connection to PRODUCTION does work on some occasions.

Comment: Well, I don't think this is an `odbc`-vs-`RODBC` thing, but since I'm not familiar with (nor able to test) `MultiSubnetFailover`, I don't know that I can offer anything significant there. However, the error message (*"is not an open RODBC channel"*) suggests that either it did not succeed the first time, or it has timed out or something else is going on outside of the DSN option. I apologize that I cannot offer specific help with that option or with the package, just trying to think of other ways that error could come up.

Comment: @r2evans That's okay. I appreciate the time and help. I'll see what I can do.